# Seeking Hook Whenever a Custom Taxonomy Term Has Been Added

Tags: hooks

I'm looking for a hook that fires whenever a new term is added to a custom taxonomy.

I tried `set_object_terms` and `create_category` but I can't get them to work it seems.

I need a hook that will fire whenever someone adds a term when creating a new Post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_category` runs when a new *category* is created, in turn `set_object_terms` fires after a terms have been *set* to object.

The hooks you are looking for are:

- [create_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/)  - new term in a specific taxonomy is created
- [created_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/) - new term created, term cache has been cleaned
- create_term
- created_term